# LINQ. Same db on different servers

Tags: asp.net, database, linq-to-sql

I want to update/insert two identical dbs on different servers. But after I've created two .dbml files I've got a lot of compilation errors such as:

> Error 28  A partial method may not have multiple defining declarations

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need two different .dbml files. What you need to do is create two different database contexts using the same dbml, but using different connection strings. Also, you should consider transaction options, but that is another question.

Comment: Now I'm trying to separate them through different namespaces. and if i would stack i will follow your solution.

Comment: That is still not what you need. If the databases have identical schemas, just create two instances of the exact same database context class, using different connection strings in the constructor.